# Mysql ID seperated by comma with join

Tags: mysql, database, group-by, concatenation, left-join

```
SELECT
p.products_id as ArtID,
p.products_model as Artikelnummer,
p.products_id as ArtID,
p.products_ean as EAN,
p.products_sort as "Master Sort",
p.products_master_slave_order as "Int. Sort",
d.products_name as Artikelname,
d.products_short_description as Kurzbeschreibung,
d.products_description as Beschreibung,
u.url_text as url_text,
FORMAT(p.products_vpe_value,1) as VPE,
CONCAT(FORMAT(p.products_price,2)," EUR") as "VK Netto",
FORMAT(p.products_weight,3) as Gewicht,
p.products_shippingtime as Lieferzeit,
p.products_image as Bild1,
GROUP_CONCAT(c.categories_id ORDER by 'p.products_id' SEPARATOR ',') as Kategorie,
p.products_status as Status,
p.disabled_shippings as Spedition,
d.products_keywords as "Keyword Suche",
u.meta_title as "Meta Title 55-60",
u.meta_description as "Meta Description 150"
FROM
xt_products p
left join xt_products_description d on p.products_id = d.products_id
left join xt_products_to_categories c on p.products_id = c.products_id
left join xt_seo_url u on p.products_id = u.link_id AND u.link_type = 1
```

with this statement I export a csv file with phpmyadmin. This works fine but my fail is:

```
GROUP_CONCAT(c.categories_id ORDER by 'p.products_id' SEPARATOR ',') as Kategorie,
```

Now it write all c.categories_id for the products_id in first row:

```
503 | 784,783,782,780,775,769,765,764,763,589,586,585,57...
```

but it would be great to have the c.categories_id comma separated for products_id:

```
503 | 784,783,
504 | 10,15,20
505 | 25,58,69
```

It would be great someone has a idea.

Thank you
Silvio

Answer (score 0):

I created the following test scenario to simulate your issue. You missed "**group by**" clause.

For example, I am fetching comma-separated Lastname on the basis of firstname.

```
create table scientist (id integer, firstname varchar(100), lastname varchar(100));

insert into scientist (id, firstname, lastname) values (1, 'albert', 'einstein');
insert into scientist (id, firstname, lastname) values (2, 'isaac', 'newton');
insert into scientist (id, firstname, lastname) values (3, 'marie', 'curie');
insert into scientist (id, firstname, lastname) values (4, 'albert', 'einstein2');
insert into scientist (id, firstname, lastname) values (5, 'albert', 'einstein3');
        
select firstname, 
GROUP_CONCAT(Lastname ORDER by 'id' SEPARATOR ',') lastnames 
from scientist 
group by firstname;
```

This should work

```
SELECT
p.products_id
GROUP_CONCAT(c.categories_id ORDER by 'p.products_id' SEPARATOR ',') as Kategorie,
FROM
xt_products p
left join xt_products_description d on p.products_id = d.products_id
left join xt_products_to_categories c on p.products_id = c.products_id
left join xt_seo_url u on p.products_id = u.link_id AND u.link_type = 1
group by p.products_id
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for helping. This works not. It is same result. All in first row you see in screenshot http://status.sisi-systems.ovh/phpmyadmin_output.png. You can load a dump if you like, xt_products > http://status.sisi-systems.ovh/xt_products.txt and the categories http://status.sisi-systems.ovh/xt_products_to_categories.txt. You can see in categories dump for ID 13784 for example more entries. This is what need in one line comma separated. Some ID one, some two, some more. Thanks